# Do Hospitals really provide laptops for patients?

Tags: realism, need-for-speed

In Need for Speed (2014), Julia who is admitted in a hospital asks nurse to provide her a laptop, to which the nurse provides a laptop to Julia.

> Julia: Is it possible to get a laptop?
>
> Nurse: Sure. I'll be right back.

[image]

Do Hospitals really provide laptops for patients?

Comment: I have worked in several hospitals and have never seen a hospital provide laptops or tablets to patients.  Patients are allowed to bring their own device and the hospital provides wifi service, but I have never seen a hospital that provides the actual device to patients.

Comment: Why was this person in the hospital?

Comment: @steelershark Bit late, but a car she was in was hit by a tow truck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know of several charitable organisations here in the UK that provide laptop computers for the use of patients in hospital wards, particularly for children and young people undergoing cancer treatment.

This one for example, [Charity donates laptops to teenage cancer patients](http://www.lauracranetrust.org/about-us/news/charity-donates-laptops-to-teenage-cancer-patients.aspx).

It is possible, but highly unlikely a hospital might have laptops available for other patients to use.

Comment: Interesting.  Maybe that's a UK thing or just something done for cancer patients or children.  Patients use laptops all of the time where I work, but they are their own personal devices.

Answer (score 0):

Some hospitals are doing pilot programs that provide tablets. [Here's one from a USA hospital called bedside](https://fisher.osu.edu/supplements/10/14434/PhyllisTeaterMarch2014.pdf) part of a larger mobile device effort. Probably not surprising that people love keeping informed with them. And surprisingly inexpensive compared to advanced medicine.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the hospital for 7-1/2 days.... They knew I was a business owner. In fact, I was unsure if I was even allowed to use my cell phone in the hospital and kept it hidden generally. I was in my room almost the whole time there, but was in the childrens' wing after coming out of surgery (they had no other beds.... the look I gave the nurse probably prompted her to find me a bed ASAP) and saw no evidence of any computer use at all by patients. This was a very large hospital a little outside of Cleveland, Ohio.